# using handsoap or Savon

Tags: ruby, soap, savon, handsoap

I created wsdl server with soap4r but facing unicode problems with it. 
so thought of trying savon or handsoap. 
Is there any resource where i can find how to define services and 
start a server(may be thin or something similar) with them?

Comment: no its 1.8.7 .. and ya I have set $KCODE for it ..

Comment: The reason why I asked is 1.9 is a lot more unicode-friendly, beyond what 1.8.7 + $KCODE does.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the official documentation for both libraries:

- [Savon Documentation](http://savonrb.com)
- [Handsoap Wiki](https://github.com/unwire/handsoap/wiki)

Answer (score 0):

Those are both client side libraries, so they won't be overly useful for your case.